# How would I write a function for the following pattern?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, recursive-algorithms

\begin{align}
Y(0) ={}& 1\\
Y(1) ={}& 2.5\\
Y(2) ={}& 2.5\cdot2.3\\
Y(3) ={}& 2.5\cdot 2.3\cdot 2.1\\
Y(4) ={}& 2.5\cdot 2.3\cdot 2.1\cdot 1.9\\
\vdots\,\,\,
\end{align}

How would I solve for something like $Y(1.3)$ or $Y(2.7)$? How would a function for $Y(x)$ be defined?

Comment: It's a variation of the gamma function I think.... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function.  Your function for integers is $Y(n) = 5!/(5 -n)!*(20)^n$.  I think.

Comment: Something like $y(x)=\prod_{k=0}^x (2.5-0.2k)$ is also a simple solution.

Comment: @Lovsovs But that won't by able to solve for non integers.  But it's a start.  Adjust to express this in terms of factorials and then expand using some application of the gamma function.  I didn't work out the kinks by the time Raymond Manzoni post his answer.

Comment: As explained in the Wikipedia article for the Gamma function, there are infinitely many functions that take on those values.  So the question "How would I solve for Y(1.3)" is underspecified.  What properties do you want Y to satisfy?

Comment: @fleablood Thanks, I had actually overlooked that the function needed to be defined over the reals.

Comment: $Y(n) = \prod_i=0^n (2.5 - .2k) = .2^n\prod(12.5 - k)=.2^n\Gamma(12.5)/\Gamma(12.5 - n)$ ????????  I have not idea if that is correct or not.

Comment: @fleablood: this is fine except for $12.5$. You may experiment with [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.2%5E2*gamma(13.5)%2Fgamma(13.5-2)) to be convinced (with $12.5$ you would get $4.83=2.3\times 2.1$ instead of $5.75=2.5\times 2.3$. Cheers,

Comment: I forgot that $\Gamma(n) = (n+1)!$ instead of $n!$.  Thing is it's easy to see the function is $2.5* 2.3* ..... *(2.5 - .2k)$ and that you can somehow scale this to a function involving factorials.  And factorials can be extended from stepwise integer function to a continuous real function by using the gamma function.  .... then the rest is just work..... which apparently I didn't do very well.

Answer (score 5):

We may use the [Pochhammer symbol (falling factorial )](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) once $Y(x)$ multiplied by $5^x$ :
\begin{align}
Y(x)\;5^x&=\left(\frac {25}2\right)_{x}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac {27}2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac {27}2-x\right)}\\
\\
\end{align}

Comment: I like and upvoted but .... shouldn't that be $\Gamma(25/2)$ and not $\Gamma(27/2)$?

Comment: Thanks @fleablood: don't forget that $x!=\Gamma(x+1)$ with $x=25/2$ as shown in the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Properties).

Comment: Oh... I thought $\Gamma(x) = x!$.  Guess I was wrong.  I really don't work with the gamma function much.  I remember it converts to factorials on integers so it's worth keeping in mind but otherwise I don't use it much.  And ... I guess I forgot there was an offset.  Oops.

Comment: @fleablood If you like, yu can use Guass's notation $\Pi(x)$ for $x!$ :) See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20960/why-is-the-gamma-function-shifted-from-the-factorial-by-1). Then you don't have to worry about gamma function's silly offset.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that
\begin{align*}
Y(x) &= \frac{25}{10} \cdot \frac{23}{10} \cdot \frac{21}{10} \cdots \frac{27 - 2x}{10} \\[5pt]
&= \frac{1}{10^x} \cdot \frac{(26)(25)(24)(23)(22)(21) \cdots (28-2x)(27-2x)}{(26)(24)(22)\cdots (28-2x)} \\
&= \frac{1}{10^x} \cdot
\frac{(26)(25)(24)(23)(22)(21) \cdots (2)(1)}{(26)(24)(22)\cdots (4)(2)}
\cdot \frac{(26-2x)(24-2x)(22-2x)\cdots (4)(2)}
{(26-2x)(25-2x)(24-2x)(23-2x)\cdots (2)(1)} \\
&= \frac{1}{10^x} \cdot
\frac{26!}{2^{13} 13!}
\cdot \frac{2^{13-x} (13-x)!}
{(26-2x)!} \\
&= \boxed{\frac{1}{20^x} \cdot \frac{26!}{13!} \cdot \frac{(13-x)!}{(26-2x)!}}.
\end{align*}

In particular, this gives you a closed form for integer $x$ when $x = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, 13$.

But we'd like this to work for $x > 13$ as well (when the above formula is undefined), and for real $x$ instead of just integer $x$.
In fact, the factorial function extends to a function $\Pi(z)$ for all complex $z$ except negative integers ($z! = \Pi(z) = \Gamma(z+1)$ where $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)).

Then we get
$$
Y(x) = \frac{1}{20^x} \cdot \frac{26!}{13!} \cdot \frac{\Pi(13-x)}{\Pi(26-2x)}
$$
We still have a problem when $x > 13$ is an integer: $\Pi(13-x)$ and $\Pi(26-2x)$ are undefined but we expect $Y(x)$ to still have a formula. We can employ the duplication formula which says that
$$
\Pi(2z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} 4^z \Pi(z) \Pi(z - \tfrac12)
$$
with $z = 13-x$ to obtain
\begin{align*}
Y(x)
&= \frac{1}{20^x} \cdot \frac{26!}{13!} \cdot \frac{\Pi(13-x)}{(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}})4^{13-x} \Pi(13-x)\Pi(\tfrac{25}{2} - x)} \\
&= \boxed{\left( \frac{26! \sqrt{\pi}}{13! \;4^{13}} \right) \left(\frac{1}{5^x}\right) \left(\frac{1}{\Pi(\tfrac{25}{2} - x)}\right)}.
\end{align*}

The constant term in front is of course $\Pi(\tfrac{25}{2}) = \Gamma(\tfrac{27}{2})$, so this agrees with Raymond Manzoni's answer.

Comment: +1: and since the [reciprocal gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_gamma_function) is an entire function no more problems for negative $x$.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thanks, good point!